How to make <div> element draggable/resizeable in react to achieve resizeable column in antd table?
I'm using reacts antd library to display my table contents. I want to add a feature to resize my column widths. Hence I'm wrapping the column in my  as shown below. Dragging is working fine as expected but the problem is handleMouseUp method is triggered only when I click again but not called when I release the mouse . I followed the the link https://www.w3schools.com/HOWTO/howto_js_draggable.asp to achieve it but there seems to be some problem as I stated earlier which I couldn't figure it out.
Please help me on what could be the issue with the below code
import React from 'react';
import { memo } from 'react';

const ResizeableHeaderComponent = (props: any) => {
  const onResize = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    if (event.movementX != 0) {
      event.preventDefault();
      props.onResize(event, props.index);
    }
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', onResize);
  };

  const handleMouseDown = () => {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', onResize);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {props.title}
      <div
        draggable={true}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 0,
          right: '-5px',
          width: '10px',
          height: '100%',
          zIndex: 5,
          cursor: 'col-resize'
        }}
        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default memo(ResizeableHeaderComponent);


Add the mousemove and mouseup listeners add a handleMouseUp function too.
Better to remove the draggable={true} from the div element. Because we are resizing via the mousemove event.
import React, { memo } from 'react';

const ResizeableHeaderComponent = (props: any) => {
  const onResize = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    if (event.movementX !== 0) {
      event.preventDefault();
      props.onResize(event, props.index);
    }
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', onResize);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
  };

  const handleMouseDown = () => {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', onResize);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {props.title}
      <div
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 0,
          right: '-5px',
          width: '10px',
          height: '100%',
          zIndex: 5,
          cursor: 'col-resize'
        }}
        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default memo(ResizeableHeaderComponent);


It's working as expected. Thank you for you response
